# List update and file upload using REST API failed with a SPListDataValidationException

Tags: list, sharepoint-rest-api, validation-error

I use the REST API to create list item, upload file linked to this item and update the item. For some list everything works fine and I can realize all these operations but for some other lists on the same site the creation is ok but the upload and update fail with a SPListDataValidationException.
I check that no validation is applied to the fields of the list.

Here find an extract of the send request to update a field of the list :

```
POST https://<my_site_address>/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Demandes%20de%20travaux')/items(20722) HTTP/1.1
Host: <my_host>
User-Agent: python-requests/2.21.0
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept: application/json; odata=verbose
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Type: application/json; odata=verbose
Cookie: FedAuth= <the FedAuth>
x-requestdigest: <the X-requestdigest>
X-HTTP-Method: PATCH
IF-MATCH: "1"
Content-Length: 79

{"__metadata": {"type": "SP.Data.DemandeSIListItem"}, "Nom_x0020_usuelId": 863}
```

and an extract of the response coming from the site :

```
HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
Cache-Control: private, max-age=0
Content-Type: application/json;odata=verbose;charset=utf-8
Expires: Mon, 01 Apr 2019 02:41:44 GMT
Last-Modified: Tue, 16 Apr 2019 02:41:44 GMT
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.0
X-SharePointHealthScore: 0
SPClientServiceRequestDuration: 493
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
SPRequestGuid: <the_SPRequestGuid>
request-id: <the_request-id>
X-RequestDigest: <the X-RequestDigest>
X-FRAME-OPTIONS: SAMEORIGIN
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
MicrosoftSharePointTeamServices: 15.0.0.4927
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-MS-InvokeApp: 1; RequireReadOnly
Date: Tue, 16 Apr 2019 02:41:44 GMT
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Content-Length: 179
Connection: Keep-Alive

{"error":{"code":"-2130575163, Microsoft.SharePoint.SPListDataValidationException","message":{"lang":"fr-FR","value":"\u00c9chec de la validation des donn\u00e9es de la liste."}}}
```

The same kind of response occured when I try to upload a file.
Send request:

```
POST https://<my_site>/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Demandes%20de%20travaux')/items(20722)/AttachmentFiles/add(FileName='test.txt') HTTP/1.1
Host: collab.intranet.edf.com
User-Agent: python-requests/2.21.0
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept: application/json; odata=verbose
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Type: application/json; odata=verbose
Cookie: FedAuth=<the_FedAuth>
x-requestdigest: <the_x-requestdigest>
Content-Length: 30

un test en python pour voir...
```

Response encountered :

```
HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
Cache-Control: private, max-age=0
Content-Type: application/json;odata=verbose;charset=utf-8
Expires: Mon, 01 Apr 2019 02:55:03 GMT
Last-Modified: Tue, 16 Apr 2019 02:55:03 GMT
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.0
X-SharePointHealthScore: 0
SPClientServiceRequestDuration: 347
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
SPRequestGuid: e963d39e-1f5c-5080-4007-f511401ecf1e
request-id: e963d39e-1f5c-5080-4007-f511401ecf1e
X-RequestDigest: <the x_requestdigest>
X-FRAME-OPTIONS: SAMEORIGIN
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
MicrosoftSharePointTeamServices: 15.0.0.4927
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-MS-InvokeApp: 1; RequireReadOnly
Date: Tue, 16 Apr 2019 02:55:04 GMT
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Content-Length: 179
Connection: Keep-Alive

{"error":{"code":"-2130575163, Microsoft.SharePoint.SPListDataValidationException","message":{"lang":"fr-FR","value":"\u00c9chec de la validation des donn\u00e9es de la liste."}}}
```

Do you have any idea of the reason of these failed... the error message is quite vague.
Regards.